# Laravel Eloquent: How to use Logical Grouping on a pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

My application has Users and Groups. They are related with a pivot table. The pivot table has nullable "joined" and "left" datetimes.

How do I use [Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#logical-grouping) on a pivot table?

I've tried:

```php
$this->belongsToMany(User::class)->wherePivot(function ($query) use ($time) {
    $query->where('joined', null)->orWhere('joined', '<=', $time);
})
// and "left"
;
```

and

```php
$this->belongsToMany(User::class)->where(function ($query) use ($time) {
    $query->wherePivot('joined', null)->orWherePivot('joined', '<=', $time);
})
// and "left"
;
```

but neither work. The first complains about passing a function as an argument that's expected to be a string, and the second complains about `wherePivot` not being defined.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are in the Group model you can define:

```
public function joinedbefore()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot(['your pivot-columns'])->where(function ($query)  {
      $query->where('joined', null);//orWhere...
  });
}
```

Or:

```
public function joinedbefore()
{
       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->wherePivot('joined', null)->orWherePivot('joined', '<=',$var);
}
```

Then it can be called:

```
$group = Group::find(1);//or any other way
$group->joinedbefore()->get();
```